# How install app to custom folder?

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I build my *.msi with WiX Toolset with code below and I need to install that to custom folder (not ProgramFiles).

Can i get install path from sources like file or registry key ?

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MySetup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

MyAppInstallationPath.ini file

```
[Data]
Path=V:\
```

*.wsx file

```
  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="INSTALLPATH">
      <IniFileSearch Id="MyAppInstalationPath" Type="directory" Name="MyAppInstallationPath.ini" Section="State" Key="Data" />
    </Property>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INTALLPATH" Name="MyApp">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MySetup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="F49934B4-6DE4-4EF1-8CDF-A4C758378FD5">
        <File Id="Calc" DiskId="1" Source="C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```